# Define more than one helper in a plugin file (Nuxt 3, Vue3, Vite)

Tags: plugins, vuejs3, vite, helper, nuxt3

I am working with Nuxt 3, Vue 3 and Vite, and when defining a new plugin, I was wondering if I could 'provide' more than one helper ($helper) using the same plugin file.
At the moment I've one seen the defineNuxtPlugin function to return 1 provide with 1 helper inside (one of these functions that will be available throughout of the application).

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it, separate methods with commas inside the provide return.

```
return {
    provide: {
      helper1: (...) => { ... },
      helper2: (...) => { ... },
      helper3: (...) => { ... },
      helper4: (...) => { ... },
    },
  }
```